# Why it doesn't use "<Event>" instead of "<T extends Event>"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I am just wondering to know if there is any reason the following code uses `<T extends Event>` instead of `Event> in this line` export abstract class Publisher` of the code?

```
import { Stan } from 'node-nats-streaming';
import { Subjects } from './subjects';

interface Event {
  subject: Subjects;
  data: any;
}

export abstract class Publisher<T extends Event> {
  abstract subject: T['subject'];
  protected client: Stan;

  constructor(client: Stan) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  publish(data: T['data']): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.publish(this.subject, JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        console.log('Event published to subject', this.subject);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that a [mre] other people can test in a standalone IDE, or do they need access to whatever `Subjects` is?   Are you really asking why the generic type parameter is named `T` instead of `Event` (which would shadow the existing type named `Event`)?  Or are you asking why `Publisher` is generic as opposed to specific? Without code suitable for pasting as-is into a standalone IDE I can't hazard too much of a guess here.  Even with such code, if you're asking why some code you found is written a certain way, that seems like a matter of opinion unless the person who wrote it posts the answer.

Comment: To be painfully clear: if someone just changes `class X<T extends Event> {...}` to `class X<Event> {...}`, any reference to `T` in the class body will be in error, and inside the class body there will be no relationship between the type parameter named `Event` and the existing `Event` type. This question sounds like "in `const y = "hello"; function foo(x = y) { console.log(x.toUpperCase()) }`, why did they write `y = x` instead of just `y`?  And the answer is "because that would do something completely different and broken and that `y` wouldn't be the same `y`".  Could you explain?

Comment: The full project's code could be find here: https://github.com/Zohalmohal/test3 and the example code I posted on my question is here: https://github.com/Zohalmohal/test3/blob/main/common/src/events/base-publisher.ts

Comment: Please include any relevant code directly in the question as plain text; external links are helpful supplements but they do not suffice here to be a [mre].

Comment: From your comments on the answer below it seems you are confused about generic type parameters and not asking about generics-vs-nongeneric types.  I'd say you should read [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand the difference, you need to understand what both things do.

#### `<T extends Event>`

The `T` is the name of the generic (this can be anything) `extends Event` is there so Typescript knows that you only want to allow generics that are of type Event or an implementation of it.

#### `<Event>`

Like said above a generic can be any word, like `Event`, you are basicly making a generic without any restrictions, and it will be typed as the type you passed it in.

Comment: But the `Event` interface has been defined just before the class definition. Why it doesn'r understand `<Event>` refers to that interface?

Comment: If you type `<Event>`, you are making a generic called `Event` and you are not referring to the `Event interface`, putting `extends Event` after it, makes it, like explained in the answer.

Comment: ... because it doesn't refer to that interface.  I can call my dog "King Charles III" but it doesn't mean my dog is now the ruler of England